Screen Size problem when screen size becomes small in flutter
In the above code my UI is running correctly but when the screen size becomes small the UI not working properly. I don't want to make it scrollable if the screen size becomes small. I want to keep the UI as it is when the screen size becomes small.The UI will be small but everything will be as it is like a image.
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Snake and Ladder'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7, // Adjust the height as needed
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 10,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0.1,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                    ),
                    itemCount: totalCells,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      .....
                   
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      ....
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    color: _getPlayerColor(_buildCell1),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/dice-$_diceNumber.png',
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 375.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              left: 220.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/snake-1.png',
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 440.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              left: 20.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/snake-1.png',
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 170.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              left: 260.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/snake-3.png',
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 170.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              left: 160.0, // Adjust the positioning as needed
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/snake-2.png',
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCell(int cellNumber, bool isPlayerLocation1, bool isPlayerLocation2) {
    bool isSnake = snakes.containsKey(cellNumber);
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
        color: _getCellColor(cellNumber),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Icon(
              _locationIcon,
              size: 30.0,
              color: isPlayerLocation1 ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent,
            ),
            Icon(
              _locationIcon2,
              size: 30.0,
              color: isPlayerLocation2 ? Color.fromARGB(255, 199, 75, 248) : Colors.transparent,
            ),
            if (isSnake)
              Icon(
                Icons.arrow_downward,
                size: 20.0,
                color: Colors.brown,
              ),
            Text(
              '$cellNumber',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


you can use this Widget=> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html to get the current screen size and multiply a fraction so it sizes top,right, left etc accordingly.

just put all the big widgets inside FittedBox widgets
and in each one put this : ,fit: BoxFit.contain,
FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, 
 child: //your widget
),
 FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.contain, 
 child: //your widget
),
.......

